# wpf xaml PathGeometry BezierSegment

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, pathgeometry

[image]

```html
<Canvas>
        <Path Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Fill="#440DB80D" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="2.5"
              Width="600"
              Height="200">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="590,100">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="000,020" Point2="000,250" Point3="200,200"/>
                                    <BezierSegment Point1="000,000" Point2="580,400" Point3="580,200"/>
                                    <!--<BezierSegment Point1="000,200" Point2="580,200" Point3="600,200"/>-->
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Hello.
I am trying to display an image of a figure using wpf xaml PathGeometry BezierSegment.

The path worked so far is as above.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to draw it.

Comment: Please clarify what you aim to achieve and what is wrong with what you have.

Comment: I am trying to express the green and red graphics in the image above with a PathGeometry.